# Setting up revers proxy on IIS 8.5 and Windows 2012 R2 does not work properly in some cases

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, iis-8.5

I have installed Orchard as a CMS on our web server at a different port number. This CMS works fine when I try to access it through localhost. Everything looks normal. However, I'd like to publicize it through our website as https : // MyWebsite dot com/blog which I was successful to some extent. Here is the configuration for inbound and outbound rules:

```
 <rewrite>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^http(s)?://localhost:8082/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="http{R:1}://MyWebsite.com/{R:2}" />
                    <conditions>
                    </conditions>
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="blog/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8082/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

Now here it is the problem:

1) I can access the blog like this: https :// MyWebsite dot com/blog

2) I can access SignOut link like this: http:// MyWebsite dot com/blog/SignOut

3) But, I cannot access Admin portal like this: https :// MyWebsite dot com/blog/Admin

Then, I had to create a subfolder in MyWebsite.com/blog/Admin and then I am able to access admin portal. This is not a sustainable way as I have to repeat the same exercise to access other links. What have I done wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!
Arash